# How to pass css module generated classes to components in Vue

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to use `CSS Modules`, but it seems as if vue lacks a mechanism to provide the generated class names to child component.

Suppose I have two components:

- `Table.vue`
- `TableRow.vue`

And styles like this:

```
.table {
  table-layout: auto;

  &.hover .row:hover .cell {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

The generated styles for `.row:hover` do not apply to `TableRow` anymore, and I haven't found a *nice* way to pass it to the child. The only thing I tried that works, but which is very ugly is passing the `$style` object down to the child. Once the component tree gets bigger, this is very annoying because every Component needs a `prop` and has to pass the `$style`-object on to the next children...

Answer (score 0):

You can assign class to a component using `v-bind` if they are coming from a variable

```
<div :class="list_view === 'list' ? 'at-listview' : 'at-groupview'"></div>
```

In above example `list_view` is a variable

If you want to send these classes to any component, again the concept is same but this time sending classes in a prop

```
<child-component classes_to_send="class1 class2 class" />
```

OR (using colon **:** to bind a variable )

```
<child-component :classes_to_send="class_from_variable" />
```

Now you can get these classes in `<child-component/>` props as shown below:

```
<script>
   ...
   export default:{
      props:['classes_to_send'],
   }


   ...
</script>
<template>
   <div :class="classes_to_send"></div>
</template>
```

Comment: This describes what I already knew. It seems you have to pass all the classes down yourself; i.e. there is no way to `provide` the `$style` to all children in the tree, which would make it a lot easier to use css modules across components.